# NLTK Remove invalid words

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

In the python NLTK library, you can tokenise a sentence into individual words and punctuation.
It will tokenise words that are not english and grammatically correct. How can i remove these tokens so all i have left is the grammatically correct, actual english words?

Example:

```
import nltk

sentence = "The word hello is gramatically correct but henlo is not"
sentence_tokenised = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sentence)
print(sentence_tokenised)
```

This generates:

```
['The', 'word', 'hello', 'is', 'gramatically', 'correct', 'but', 'henlo', 'is', 'not']
```

'henlo' is not an english word. Is there a function that can parse these tokens and remove the invalid words like 'henlo'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on NLTK documentation [here](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html):

> A tokenizer that divides a string into substrings by splitting on the specified string (defined in subclasses).

So what it does, it is only dividing a string into substring. If you want to filter words that are not in `nltk.corpus.words()` you can download the words one time:

```py
import nltk
nltk.download('words')
```

and then after that:

```py
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import words

sentence = "The word hello is gramatically correct but henlo is not"
sentence_tokenised = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sentence)

output = list(filter(lambda x: x in words.words(), sentence_tokenised))
```

output:

```py
['The', 'word', 'hello', 'is', 'correct', 'but', 'is', 'not']
```